# Owl Carousel 2 touchDrag by same number as slideBy possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, touch, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel 2 to display some images for a lookbook. On small screens I show only 1 image at a time. When more screen space is available I display 2 images at a time, think of it like a printed magazine.

Now, I can't figure out how to move slides when dragging (touch swipe) by 2 images on screens where 2 images get displayed at a time. So basically on bigger screens I want the same behavior when swiping as when the owl nav is pressed. Is this possible?

```
$('.lookbook-slider').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:true,
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    navText: ["<i class='icon-arrow-left4'></i>","<i class='icon-uniE64D'></i>"],
    dots:false,
    margin:0,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            slideBy:"1",
            merge:false,
            mergeFit:true
        },
        640:{
            items:2,
            slideBy:"2",
            merge:true,
            mergeFit:true
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!